# how to make Registry re-evaluate Environment variable related settings

Tags: c#, dll

I am trying to rewrite a c++ based dll in C# ( I have the dll and PDB, don't know to further make use of it ). basically what the old dll does is update some ENV variable and re evaluate registry settings that depend on these environment variables.

1. Step1. Updating the environment variable in application itself is
   easily achieved using **Environment** class.
2. Step2. the old dll uses an encapsulated dll to "force reghook to reevaluate all env.variable changes", this is the difficult part. it is not simply persist that into registry

Question 1: what does that mean by registry settings depend on environment variable ?
Question 2: what does that mean by re-evaluating those registry settings?

I am not familiar with this area , for the OLD DLL I have the DLL and SYMBOL(PDB) don't know how to reverse engineering to get related info.

[Related topic: environment-variables-propagation-on-windows-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253812/environment-variables-propagation-on-windows-system)

Comment: I suppose it could use RegNotifyChangeKeyValue() to detect changes to the system environment registry variables as stored in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment.  It makes little sense for a program to actually do this.  If you don't know why or what it does then you of course have little hope of replacing it.